# Why can't I access WAMP web server outside of LAN using no-ip?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

Installed WAMP latest version on my Windows 10 machine.

Put my website in my www directory.

I changed the listening port of my server to 1337 because my isp blocks port 80.

I installed no-ip and set up a host, homewebtest

Well when I disconnect from my LAN and use a different connection outside of my LAN, when I visit homewebtest, for some reason it brings me to my pfsense router config page which is 10.12.1.1

So I try homewebtest:1337 and it just times out.

I allowed port 1337 through my firewall.

I port forwarded port 1337 to 10.12.1.131 which is the ip that WAMP is running on.

I restarted thr services after committing the changes.

When I'm on my LAN, all of my devices can access 10.12.1.1:1337. They just cant access it via a no-ip address when outside of the LAN. I also clicked "put online."

i.imgur.com/D62h7Bg.png

Clearly shows that I didn't point it to 10.12.1.1.

i.imgur.com/57Brf9B.png

Clearly shows that using the specified dynamic DNS name I've created, it attempts to connect to pfsense but rejects it because it thinks its an attack.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u99Ng.png

After adding the dynamic dns I've created to a whitelist on pfsense, it no longer thinks the connection is an attack, so it lets me login to my routers configuration page(specified on 10.12.1.1) from an external connection outside of my LAN using my dynamic DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

You have your dynamic DNS service setup wrong.

You say,

> "when I disconnect from my LAN and use a different connection outside of my LAN, when I visit homewebtest, for some reason it brings me to my pfsense router config page which is 10.12.1.1"

That means `homewebtest` doesn't point to your public IP, it is pointing to your routers internal IP.

But, some of the information you provided is conflicting - because if you were truly connected to a different connection outside of your LAN, you wouldn't get access to your router's configuration page at 10.12.1.1.

So, I have to say, not only are you not connected to a different network, your dynamic DNS is setup wrong. It should be assigning your public IP address to the dynamic domain name you setup.

I think you are just just obscuring the real domain name, but you do know that the domain name is actually something like homewebtest.dyndns.org?

You made no mention of the dynamic dns service you were using, or how you configured it. So, recheck your installation and settings.

Comment: Yeah I'm obscuring it. no-ip.org is the dynamic dns service I'm using. When I say I'm using a different connection outside of my LAN, I turn the wifi off on my phone. So instead of using LAN wifi on my phone, I use cellular 4g data which is outside of my LAN.

Comment: When you set up a host using no-ip.org, it defaults to using your public IP address. So I didn't set it to point to 10.12.1.1. It defaulted to my WAN IP/

Comment: Just telling you what your original question specifies. What you said in your question is not possible if those two things you just commented on are true. sorry.

Comment: Is it possible some of your information is inaccurate? Are you sure accessing homewebtest from outside the network takes you to your pfsense firewall specifically "at 10.12.1.1"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/D62h7Bg.png

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/57Brf9B.png

Comment: Using the dyndns name brings me to pfsense. It blocks the request because it thinks its an attack. When I add the dyndns name to a whitelist on pfsense, then it directs me to pfsense and lets me log into my router.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/iUHs3JA.png